# Accessing a particular TextView in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

Here's the particulars of my problem. I have a RecyclerView representing multiple games a user currently has active. In each of the child Views of the RecyclerView, there is CountDownTimer running independently. I need refresh the CountDownTimer for a given game upon receiving a push notification indicating that a particular game has been updated.

In general terms, how would I go about doing this after the push notification has been received? Each of the Views held by the RecyclerView contains a GameID, so I was thinking that I may be able to access the View and its CountDownTimer using the GameID packaged in the push notification?

Not sure how to proceed here, all help is appreciated.

Comment: So you have some kind of adapted with your recycler. I'm thinking - loop though it, compare gameID, change what you need once you find the match and call notify.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have attached model to your view, you just need to update this model and notify adapter about it.